# How can I store REST response(s) inside a datasource loop to a properties test step

Tags: soapui

I'm making essentially 5 separate requests to the same REST service inside a datasource loop that returns a encrypted string. How do I store the response from each iteration? I should have 5 different encrypted strings stored after the loop. I don't want to store them to a external excel or csv file, which is what the datasink step is for right?

Comment: So where would you like to store them? What are you going to do with them afterwards? As it is, this question is too broad.

Comment: @SiKing, would like to store them in a properties test step to ultimately use outside in another test case.